# Code color styling in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, colors

A nice simple question: Is there something similar to http://studiostyl.es/ for Eclipse?

**Update**: Since I used this link to figure out how to use the plugin, I figured I'd put it here.
http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=plugin

That site is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have a look at http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/, also directly available in the marketplace.