# is there any way to install a theme in Eclipse IDE ?

Tags: eclipse, colors, themes

I'm learning some Java programming using the latest eclipse version (kepler I think) which is good except the built-in text editor with a white background which is not good for someone like me who used to program with Sublim Text so i want to know if I can change the theme and how ?

thank's

Comment: This answer certainly answers it:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/5826004/793607

Answer (score 0):

If you merely want to change the background color, you find the setting at 'Windows  > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors'.

Depending on your choice it might be, that the syntax highlighting doesn't contrast too good with your new background color. It that case I would suggest, that you use an editor theme, which can be installed with the [Eclipse Color Theme](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-color-theme) Plugin.

Comment: Thanks ! :) with some googling I also found the sublime text theme for eclipse http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=theme&id=66